# Зачем return после редиректа?

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript

Есть система авторизации. Вот её основная часть:

```
  private authUser(): void {
    if(!this.login.trim().length || !this.password.trim().length) { 
        alert('Заполните поля');
        return;
    };

    for(var prop in this.users) {
      if (!this.users.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;
      if(this.users[prop].login == this.login.trim() && this.users[prop].password == this.password.trim()) {
            this.globalVarsService.authUser = this.users[prop];
            this.router.navigate(['/main']); 
        return;
      } 
    }

    alert('Ошибка авторизации. Нет такого пользователя.');
  };
```

Здесь много кода, но главное в том, что если срабатывает условие if в цикле for, то происходит редирект на страницу приложения. А если цикл for не находит ни одного совпадения, то выводится сообщение.

Мне непонятно почему эта конструкция работает только если после команды редиректа стоит команда return. Без неё даже при успешной авторизации сначала выводится сообщение и только после этого происходит редирект

Comment: Асинхронность как она есть

Comment: Но здесь же нет ни аякса, ни подобного ничего

Comment: Метод `this.router.navigate()` асинхронен. Иными словами, он помещает заявку в браузерную очередь на обработку и тут же возвращает управление обратно в скрипт.

Comment: даже если бы он был синхронный, то `return` всё равно был бы нужен, потому что в angular навигация между страницами происходит без перезагрузки страницы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

return завершает функцию до того, как будет выведено сообщение об ошибке и выступает в качестве else.

```
Аналогичный код:
 function fn(val){
     if(val===3){
         alert("gg");
         return;
     }
     alert("not gg");
 }
```